# Is my thought correct？

Tags: functional-analysis

A question from my problem sheet.

For $t\in \mathbb R^+$. We have the operator $T_t$ where $$(T_tg )(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int exp(-y^2/2t)g(y-x)dy $$
for all functions $g$ which the expression  is well defined

I am asked to prove or disprove that $$T_t\in B(L_1,L_\infty) $$

Where $ B(L_1,L_\infty)$ is the set of bounded linear operator from $L_1 $ to $L_\infty$ .

I am thinking of taking $g=1$ then the $$(T_tg )(x)=1$$ the expression is well defined but $g$ is not in $L_1$ . Then we disprove this statement. Is there anything wrong with my thought because I am afraid that things are not always that simple

Comment: You should take something in $L_1$ and see if it gets mapped to something in $L_\infty$. Also check to see if it's bounded.

Comment: ohhhh. Now  I think your statement is what I am supposed to do...... Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is uniformly and crudely bounded by $1/\sqrt{2\pi t}$. Therefore,
$$
          \|T_tg\|_{\infty} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\|g\|_{1}.
$$